# Radio button function not working properly when rows dynamically added by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, radio-button

I am fetching values from database via json, and in parallel I am adding radio buttons with 3 options. However, when trying to make a selection I face below issue.

If you run the code and try to select Green for all 3 options, the option keeps jumping from 1 row to another. If you want to select Green for all 3, its not letting it.

My aim is to update the database back with either of 3 options and store the value in json object as status.

My purpose is to make selection out of 3 options and pass it back to database and update. Please help!

```js
type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var appStatus = [{
            "category": "Overall Status",
            "status": "0"
        }, {
            "category": "System Availability",
            "status": "0"
        }, {
            "category": "Whatever 2",
            "status": "0"
        }];
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < appStatus.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + appStatus[i].category + "</td>");
            tr.append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions []" value="1" checked="checked" id="inlineRadio1"><font color="green">Green &emsp;</font><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions1 []" id="inlineRadio2" value="YELLOW"><font color="yellow">Yellow &emsp;</font></label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions1 []" id="inlineRadio3" value="Red"> <font color="red">Red</font></label><td></tr>');
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover"><thead>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Status</th>
</thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just to give them the same name like the following snippet shows.

Then if you want to get the new values, you could loop through the tr's :

```
var new_status = [];
$('.table tbody tr').each(function(){
   new_status.push( {category: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(),status: $(this).find(':radio:checked').val()});
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var appStatus = [{
      "category": "Overall Status",
      "status": "0"
    }, {
      "category": "System Availability",
      "status": "0"
    }, {
      "category": "Whatever 2",
      "status": "0"
    }];
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < appStatus.length; i++) {
      tr = $('<tr/>');
      tr.append("<td>" + appStatus[i].category + "</td>");
      tr.append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" value="1" checked="checked" id="inlineRadio1"><font color="green">Green &emsp;</font><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio2" value="YELLOW"><font color="yellow">Yellow &emsp;</font></label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio3" value="Red"> <font color="red">Red</font></label><td></tr>');
      $('table').append(tr);
    }
    
    
    $('#result').on('click',function(){
        var new_status = [];
        $('.table tbody tr').each(function(){
            new_status.push( {category: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(),status: $(this).find(':radio:checked').val()});
        });
        
        console.log(new_status);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </thead>
</table>

<button id="result">Result</button>
```

Comment: Much thanks, Zakaria! I have another on-top question for you here. If you see in my script, I am manually giving inputs as json objects. Lets assume I receive current status of the categories as (green/yellow/red) or (1/2/3) for the categories already in the DB via json. How can I display the current status as pre-selected radio-button for the values received; and so that when I update, its parsed on same way.  eg: assume "System Availability", comes with "status": "3" or "red", how can I display red pre-selected as page loads? Thanks again, really appreciate your expertise!